# how to get visibility on systemd unit lifecycle?

Tags: systemd

Had a weird case of sshd not starting up on a vm, when the host had no external network. Turned out the dev linux image i was using (do not dismiss this as an oddity, it is the same on arch, ubuntu, debian, gentoo, rhel...) had some unit files creating a chain based on `Before=` instead of `After=` that dependend on `timesyncd` running successfully. And nothing would show me those `Before`ed dependencies.

```
#sshd.service
[service]
After=network.target

#pacman-init.service
Before=sshd.service cloud-final.service archlinux-keyring-wkd-sync.service
After=time-sync.target
ConditionFirstBoot=yes
```

So, after firstboot, whenever i would start this machine with a host without access to the ntp server, systemd will just gaslight me.

`systemctl start sshd` <- nothing happens. no failure. no timeouts. nothing on any log! Wait for 3h and still no idea what is happening.

`systemctl list-dependencies sshd` <- not a single mention of the impacting service!

`systemctl list-dependencies --all sshd` <- all option doesn't seem to add anything other than irrelevant slice info.

going online would then complete the ntp update, satisfy `pacman-init.service`'s `After=time-sync.target`, see that `ConditionFirstBoot=yes` doesn't apply anymore, ignore `pacman-init` and starts `sshd.service`. sigh.

without going online, i had to understand the problem parsing processed units, so that the irrelevant service `Before` would be appended to the relevant service's `After` attribute and i could learn about them.

```
for u in `systemctl show sshd | grep After= | cut -d= -f2`; do systemctl status $u; done
```

and that was the **only** way to see that pacman-init.service was a dependency and was holding things.

**So, my question is not how to solve any of that. The question is how exactly should i have gained information about this, as a systemd operator?**

---

edit:

another systemd terrible user experience.

system sleeps. Returns from sleep in the year 2076!

```
$ timedatact
              Local time: Sun 2076-09-20 11:14:27 UTC
           Universal time: Sun 2076-09-20 11:14:27 UTC
                 RTC time: Fri 2023-05-12 17:39:40
                Time zone: UTC
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Great, it knows the RTC clock is *minutes* from the time it woke up, but for some reason it decides to set the clock to 2076 instead.

There's no command to set clock from rtc...

I enable network and try a naive `restart systemd-timedated`. Of course, it fails with absolutely no information about why. not even what it was trying to do. just fail.

Let's look at what it was trying to run. Oh, look. the unit file is a binary. thanks for nothing.

let's try the only somewhat-debug command available in the entire time setting mess (like it is not that important, right?)

```
timedatectl show-timesync -a --monitor
Failed to parse bus message: No such file or directory
```

which file? why do you want to know, just suffer systemd! ...just in case i made sure all the usual config files mentioned in the docs are available and readable with the original contents. Same error.

the great usability work around: re-type the date you get from hardware clock manually! ...and do it FAST to not skew the clock more. or waste even more time with a one-of script.

```
timedatectl set-time '...'
```

Comment: Your edit and your original problem seem to be unrelated except in that both are in systemd. They should be separate questions.

Comment: i figured they both related to the awful experience of being an operator of systemd in general. no logs anywhere, no status anywhere, no visibility on dependency chain, etc, etc, etc. the edit just adds that even the native implemented core services are worse than the problems with ones that call external daemons. ...but i guess you have a good point. will split it.